# Give a formal proof for associativity of Cartesian product (assuming Kuratowski's pair ordering)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to give some sort of exact proof for why associativity will hold for the Cartesian product assuming for the following that:

(a,b,c)→ ((a,b),c)

and so,

(A×B)×C={((a,b),c): a∈A, b∈B, c∈C}.

Because of the ordering, the associativity is assumed to hold and be isomorphic.

My question is how to prove the Cartesian product associativity formally. Do I just assume a belongs to A? Would I include a possibility or case in the proof where a is not a member of A?

The question is written as: Prove or refute that Ax(BxC) = (AxB)xC.

I have already refuted it with a counterexample, which is here:
Let A = {1}, B = {2} and C = {3}.

Then (A x B ) x C = { ( (1, 2), 3 ) } 
and A x (B x C) = { (1, (2, 3) ) }.

Assuming the bijection though, between the ordered pair and single and (a,b,c), I would like to prove the identity, mainly because we are using Kuratowski's work on sets in the class this for.

I found a similar question with an answer that has a proof for the associativity, but I am not using functions yet. That is here:

[What am I working with? [Inferring a theory in Category Theory using associativity of Cartesian Product]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372422/what-am-i-working-with-inferring-a-theory-in-category-theory-using-associativi)

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: **Because of the ordering, the associativity is assumed to hold and be isomorphic.** This sentence makes no sense. If you could improve it, the question might become clearer to you and us.

Answer (score 1):

You are right in noting that, formally, $(A\times B)\times C$ and $A\times(B\times C)$ are different. Ordered pairs have the following property:
$$(a,b)=(c,d)\qquad\text{ if and only if }\qquad a=c\text{ and }b=d$$

So indeed, if you take $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$ and $C=\{3\}$, we have $(A\times B)\times C=\{((1,2),3)\}$ and $A\times(B\times C)=\{(1,(2,3))\}$. The elements $((1,2),3)$ and $(1,(2,3))$ are distinct by the property above, since their first entries are distinct: $1\neq (1,2)$.

However, in general, there is a natural bijection between $(A\times B)\times C$ and $A\times(B\times C)$, namely $((a,b),c)\mapsto (a,(b,c))$. We usually use this bijection to identify these two sets.

From a categorical point of view, $A\times (B\times C)$ and $(A\times B)\times C$ will always be isomorphic (if the category we are on has products), but this is a more advanced topic.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I was curious to know what you meant by, 'if the category we are on has products'. I know category theory and the cartesian product have close ties, so just wanted to check. Also, to prove ax(bxc)=(axb)xc, I am just stating the bijection identity, as it has been mentioned here to do. I hope that suffices as a proof.

Answer (score 0):

Using Kuratowsky's $(x,y):=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$, we have
$$ ((x,y),z)=(\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\},z)=\{ \{\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}\},\{\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\},z\} \}$$
and 
$$ (x,(y,z)) = (x,\{\{y\},\{y,z\}\})=\{\{x\},\{x,\{\{y\},\{y,z\}\}\}\}$$
Note in particular that $\{x\}\in(x,(y,z))$, but without strange coincidences among $x,y,z$, we do not have $\{x\}\in ((x,y),z)$.

However, we have a *canonical bijection* from $(A\times B)\times C$ to $A\times(B\times C)$ by mapping $((x,y),z)\mapsto (x,(y,z))$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I just needed to see it a few times to actually understand this relationship. A few other posts explained the bijection, but I think seeing the ordering helped, for me. Thanks again.